# Does pyrax use servicenet if it's possible, or should I set it manually?

Tags: python, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles, pyrax

I'm using pyrax to manipulate Rackspace Cloud Files.
Can I force pyrax to use servicenet instead of publicnet, or is it choosen automatically?

In django-cumulus settings we have `settings.CUMULUS['SERVICENET']` parameter to handle it, but I didn't found, how to set this param to pyrax itself.

```
import pyrax

cls = pyrax.utils.import_class('pyrax.identity.rax_identity.RaxIdentity')
pyrax.identity = cls()
pyrax.set_setting('region', <REGION>)
pyrax.set_credentials(<USERNAME>, <API_KEY>)
cf = pyrax.cloudfiles
rackspace_media_container = cf.get_container(<CONTAINER>)
```

Where can I tell pyrax to use servicenet?

Comment: Did my answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set public to `False` when creating the connection, explicitly:

```
cf = pyrax.connect_to_cloudfiles(region=<REGION>, public=False)
```

Documentation on `connect_to_cloudfiles`:

> Creates a client for working with cloud files. The default is to
>   connect to the public URL; if you need to work with the ServiceNet
>   connection, pass False to the 'public' parameter.

Source: [pyrax/**init**.py, connect_to_files method](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/blob/0ffa2dc7e1df98e8d2be26bffce169339684fa9e/pyrax/__init__.py#L650-L654).

Comment: Thx for expanding the answer, @kyle-kelley!